# Nestjs getting 404 on e2e test but expected 400 (chai & supertest)

Tags: testing, nestjs, chai, e2e-testing, supertest

Hello Fellow Programmers, i just bumped into a problem that would like to get another eyes into.

As im running e2e tests, in this function
[image]

im getting this error
[image]

Which seems odd, because when im testing on swagger or postman the request behaves as expected as you can see here
[image]

this is my **module** on the test file

[image]

Do you happen to know what the solution might be?, let me know below :)
Also, if you need more info just let me know and i'll update this question.

Already made sure that the address it's sending the request to is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Would it be possible that the server is not fully initialized when you run your API call? An asynchronous problem?

Look at that test template, maybe that would work? Sorry I cannot test, I'm on phone / vacation.

Test template : https://github.com/befabry/nest-car-value/blob/master/test/auth.e2e-spec.ts

Answer (score 0):

The problem was I wasn't passing the request body correctly in the controller, which i solved adding the following decorator to the method, which validates the body and returns the expected 400:

`@UsePipes(new ValidationPipe({ transform: true, whitelist: true }))`

Comment: I don't think you should have to do that. Normally NestJS takes care of it if you set it up globally through the main.ts entry file.

How to set it up : https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/validation#auto-validation=

app.useGlobalPipes(new ValidationPipe());